# How do I use a custom function as a Python SVM kernel?

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm

All, I have a question about how to generate a custom SVM kernel in Python that I have not quite found the answer for.

In particular, I'm trying to understand how to make a kernel with a custom function, not merely a polynomial.

Below is a plot of what I would like to use as a kernel:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBIow.png)

My (naive) approach was to base myself on the examples of linear kernels found in the SVM documentation with this function, in a manner like:

`def testKernel(function, classifiers):
    return np.dot(function, classifiers.T)`

But that just throws errors (as I guessed it would but I figured I might as well try). So, that's the question: How do I make a kernel using a custom function?

Comment: Hi. Which library do you use for your SVM ? Is it your own library ?

Comment: I've just been using the library that Python 2.7 provides in the scikit learn package.

Comment: So you are using scikit-learn (Python doesn't provide it). Maybe this could help : http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_custom_kernel.html

Comment: That's what I found at first, but I haven't figured out how to modify that kernel to really do what I need it to do. I also found another snippet of code that generates a degree 3 polynomial, which is closer to what I want, but not quite:
`   def poly_kernel(x, y):
       degree = 3
       return np.dot(x, y.T) ** 3`

Comment: Ok so that's more a Machine Learning specific question right ? Maybe you should ask this question there : http://stats.stackexchange.com